# Is it possible to modify error message of "Index was outside the bounds of the array"?

Tags: c#, error-handling

Sometimes getting error "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I know what it is and how to fix it.

**The question is:**

is it possible to modify error message (global for this type of error) to **add wrong index number and array length** - it will be very helpful.

Comment: With you edit now mentioning global, I don't think that's possible. It wouldn't really be that helpful. If you're taking user input you should accept and validate the user's input. If it's your own code, then you should be aware of the length of the array (ideally using `arrayName.Length` or `arrayName.Count()`).

Comment: You should be checking and validating things before it throws an error if its excepted. 

Exception message are for developers not users. However you can (if you dont mind destroying the stack trace) rethrow a new exception  `throw new MyAwesomExceptionOfSomeType("With my awesome message");` however i would use this as a last resort and think about the design a little more

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to catch "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception globally, you can subscribe to unhundled exceptions and catch it there. Here is an example:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;


private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ExceptionObject is IndexOutOfRangeException outOfRangeException)
    {
       // do something 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify how your post answers " to add wrong index number and array length "?